# Difference between opening a file in binary vs text

Tags: c++, file, text, binary

I've done some stuff like:

```
FILE* a = fopen("a.txt", "w");
const char* data = "abc123";
fwrite(data, 6, 1, a);
fclose(a);
```

and then in the generated text file, it says "abc123" just like expected. But then I do:

```
//this time it is "wb" not just "w"
FILE* a = fopen("a.txt", "wb");
const char* data = "abc123";
fwrite(data, 6, 1, a);
fclose(a);
```

and get the exact same result. If I read the file using binary or normal mode, it also gives me the same result. So my question is, what is the difference between fopening with or without binary mode.

Where I read about fopen modes: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: Try opening the file in text mode on Windows and writing a bunch of newlines into it, then try reading it back.

Comment: Yes, I now see the duplicate. Apologies for not noticing it before

Comment: Side note: I noticed you tagged this with C++, not C. Might I suggest using `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` instead of the C library? It's more idiomatic and ensures that you don't need to worry about remembering to call close, irrespective of whether or not an exception is thrown (in addition to providing other nice abstractions).

Comment: Note that the linked to duplicate's selected solution is **incorrect** in some details, as I'm writing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The link you gave does actually describe the differences, but it's buried at the bottom of the page:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

> Text files are files containing sequences of lines of text. **Depending on the environment where the application runs, some special character conversion may occur in input/output operations in text mode to adapt them to a system-specific text file format**. Although on some environments no conversions occur and both text files and binary files are treated the same way, using the appropriate mode improves portability.

The conversion could be to normalize `\r\n` to `\n` (or vice-versa), or maybe ignoring characters beyond 0x7F (a-la 'text mode' in FTP). Personally I'd open everything in binary-mode and use a good Unicode or other text-encoding library for dealing with text.

Comment: I wasn't planning on dealing with text anyways so that is good. For some reason I can't accept until 10 minutes later.

Answer (score 8):

The most important difference to be aware of is that with a stream opened in text mode you get **newline translation** on non-*nix systems (it's also used for network communications, but this isn't supported by the standard library). In *nix newline is just ASCII linefeed, `\n`, both for internal and external representation of text. In Windows the external representation often uses a carriage return + linefeed pair, "CRLF" (ASCII codes 13 and 10), which is converted to a single `\n` on input, and conversely on output.

---

From the C99 standard (the N869 draft document), §7.19.2/2,

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line
>   consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the
>   last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters
>   may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing
>   conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-
>   to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation. Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data
>   that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing
>   characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is
>   immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character.
>   Whether space characters that are written out immediately before a new-line character
>   appear when read in is implementation-defined.

And in §7.19.3/2

> Binary files are not truncated, except as defined in 7.19.5.3. Whether a write on a text
>   stream causes the associated file to be truncated beyond that point is implementation-
>   defined.

About use of `fseek`, in §7.19.9.2/4:

> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by
>   an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`.

About use of `ftell`, in §17.19.9.4:

> The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file. For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.

I think that’s the most important, but there are some more details.