# Should the binary output be the same as the ASCII input?

Tags: c, ascii, binaryfiles

I'm writing a program that reads an ASCII file and then converts it to a Binary file, as I see it's not such a hard task, but understanding what's happening behind is ...

As I understand, an ASCII file is just human readable text, so if we want to create a new file full of ASCII's, a simple loop with a `fputc()` would be enough and for a binary file `fwrite()` will do the job right?

So my question here is, once that the ASCII to Binary conversion is done, what should I see in my `.bin` file? It should be filled with exactly the same symbols `<88><88><88><88><88>`?

Code:

```
/*
*  From "Practical C Programming 2nd Edition"
*  Exercise 14-4: Write a program that reads an ASCII file containing a list of numbers
*  and writes a binary file containing the same list. Write a program that goes the
*  other way so that you can check your work.
*
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *in_filename = "bigfile.txt";
const char *out_filename = "out_file.bin";

int main()
{

    int ch = 0;

    /* ASCII */
    FILE *in_file = NULL;

    in_file = fopen(in_filename, "r");

    if(!in_file)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not open file %s ... ", in_filename);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Binary */
    FILE *out_file = NULL;

    out_file = fopen(out_filename, "w+b");

    if(!out_file)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: New file %s, could not be created ... ", out_filename);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    while(1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(in_file);
            if(ch == EOF)
                break;
            else
               fwrite(in_file, sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
    }

        fclose(in_file);
        fclose(out_file);

    return 0;

}
```

I'm generating the input file with this shell script:

```
tr -dc "0-9" < /dev/urandom | fold -w100|head -n 100000 > bigfile.txt
```

Any help would be very appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your assignment, but as I read it, you want to read your ASCII test file as *numbers*, perhaps using `fscanf(in_file, "%d", &ch)`.  If you do it that way, an input file containing "18 52 86 120" would result in a 4-byte binary output file containing the four bytes `0x12`, `0x34`, `0x56`, and `0x78`.

Comment: And if you can get it to work that way, if you give it the input `72 101 108 108 111 44 32 119 111 114 108 100 33 10`, you should end up with a "binary" output file that's actually also a text file, after all...

Comment: Your question here "what should I see in the output, should it be same/different to input?" is the first thing I'd like to ask you and the first thing I'd be asking my instructor. It's not an English course, where the aim is to understand what the question is getting at - it's a programming one. As written, the question feels poor. I'd expect a sample of the input and output as a minimum...

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for the suggestion, I just changed the title, and sorry for the poor writing, English isn't my first language.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the comment, I would like to ask you about a good resource to better understand these topics , since the book that I currently read I believe is very limited in certain aspects...

Comment: @PaulS-Pou - oooh. I didn't realize how my comment could be ambiguous. Your question here is of much higher standard than many and was refreshing to read. :thumbs-up: My complaint lay with the person that originally wrote Exercise 14-4. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file in text mode or binary mode has nothing to do with ASCII/binary conversion.
It has to do with how the operating system deals with some special characters (such as new line characters), line size limit or file extensions.

In the [fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) Linux man page:

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of the  two-character  strings  de‐
> scribed  above.   This  is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.  (Other
> systems may treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that  your  program
> may be ported to non-UNIX environments.)

For more information about opening a file in text or binary mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863975/6874310

Now, back to the ASCII conversion:

All the data in a computer is stored in bits so in the end everything is binary.

A text file containing ASCII characters is also a binary file, except its contents can be mapped to the ASCII table characters in a meaningful way.

Have a look at the [ASCII table](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html). The ASCII character number zero (`0`) has a binary value of `0x30`. This means that the zero you see in a text file is actually
a binary number `0x30` in the memory.

Your program is reading data from a file and writing to another file without performing any ASCII/binary conversion.

Also, there is a small error here:

```
fwrite(in_file, sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
```

It probably should be:

```
fwrite(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
```

This writes the byte in variable `ch` to `out_file`.
With this fix, the program basically reads data from the file `bigfile.txt` and write the very same data to the file `out_file.bin` without any conversion.

To convert a single digit ASCII number to binary, read the digit from your input file in a byte (`char` type) and subtract `0x30` from it:

```
char ch = fgetc(in_file);

if(ch == EOF)
{
    break;
}
else if (isdigit(ch))
{
   ch = ch - 0x30;
   fwrite(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
}
```

Now, your output file will be actually binary.
Use `isdigit`to ensure the byte is an ASCII number. Add `#include <ctype.h>` in the beginning of your file to use it.

So, for a small input file with the following text:

```
123
```

Its binary representation will be:

```
0x313233
```

And, after the ASCII numbers are converted to binary, the binary contents will be:

```
0x010203
```

To convert it back to ASCII, simply reverse the conversion. That is, add `0x30` to each byte of the binary file.

If you're using a Unix-like system, you can use command line tools such as `xxd` to check binary files. On Windows, any Hex Editor program will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it solved every doubt that I had in the beginning, I don't know why I imagined that using the b flag on the `fopen()` would do the magic. but this solves all my doubts, really appreciate this.

Comment: Cool! I remember I was confused when I was learning this for the first time. Some tutorials are pretty vague when explaining these flags.

Answer (score 2):

```
fwrite(in_file, sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
```

is wrong because an integer is given where a pointer is expected.

You can use `fputc` to write one byte like

```
fputc(in_file, out_file);
```

If you still want to use `fwrite` for some reason, prepare a data to write and write that like

```
{
    unsigned char in_file_byte = in_file;
    fwrite(&in_file_byte, sizeof(in_file_byte), 1, out_file);
}
```

Now the contents of the output file will be the same as the input file. Some system may perform conversion of newline characters and it may make the contents differ because the input file is opened in text mode.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've already tried to replace the `fwrite()` with `fgetc()`, but that makes me doubt more, because now I have the same input and output, even when the output should be different, because ASCII and binary files should not look the same right?

Comment: @PaulS-Pou They should look the same if no conversion is performed. It is just matter of how to interpret the data (bytes).