# PPM image gets distorted when writing binary data but does not when writing string (ASCII)

Tags: c, image, ppm

i have pointer to data buffer.
when i write PPM image using string (ASCII), it's written successfully without any distortion.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYAFY.png
but when i do the same thing but write binary data instead it gets distorted. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaL72.png

I'v spent hours and i still don't know what is the problem.
this is the code for the string writing

```
FILE *f;
int i;
f = fopen(filename,"w");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("cant open the file \n");
}
fprintf(f, "P3\n%d %d\n%d\n", xsize, ysize, 255);
for (i = 0; i < ysize * xsize * 3; i++){
    fprintf(f, "%u\n", buf[i]);
}
fclose(f);
```

this is the code for the binary writing

```
FILE *f;
int i;
f = fopen(filename,"w");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("cant open the file \n");
}
fprintf(f, "P6\n%d %d\n%d\n", xsize, ysize, 255);
for (i = 0; i < ysize * xsize * 3; i++){
    fwrite(buf + i, 1, 1, f);
}
fclose(f);
```

please help!

Comment: Does `f = fopen(filename,"wb");` help?

Comment: The explanation can be found, e.g., in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863959/difference-between-opening-a-file-in-binary-vs-text).

Answer (score 0):

for people who had the same problem.
just make sure to use

```
fopen("filename.ext", "wb")
```

instead of

```
fopen("filename.ext", "w")
```

this is an explanation for why to use "wb" for binary instead of "w".  
[Difference between opening a file in binary vs text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863959/difference-between-opening-a-file-in-binary-vs-text)